# How to do hypothesis test if we only know part of the sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

Basically, I am facing a problem where I need to do a hypothesis test with the Null hypothesis being Y ~ Norm(u,q) while I only know the sample size is 'n' and the number of samples between 0 and 5 is 'k'.

Comment: u and q are known

Comment: You cannot test your hypothesis of you don't even have access to at least one data point... Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not given any of the *usual* information for a test of hypothesis.
Maybe the scenario below is a clue to the approach you're expected to take.

Suppose I'm told that $u=\mu = 10, \sigma=3,$ $q=\theta=\sigma^2 = 9,$ and I know $n = 20,$ $k = 5.$

Then $P(0 < Y \le 5) = 0.0474$ with $\mu=10, \sigma=3.$ 
(Computation in R below.)

```
diff(pnorm(c(0,5), 10, 3))
[1] 0.04736129
```

If getting $0 < Y \le 5$ is a Success, should I get as many as $k=5$ Successes in $n=20$ observations?

```
1 - pbinom(4,20,.0474)
[1] 0.002037408
```

Comment: Yes! If p = P(0<Y≤5) and K ~ B(n, p), we can get std(K) = sqrt(n, p, (1-p)). Then we can get the Confidence interval of K is [p*n - 2* std(K), p*n + 2*std(K)]. Then we can test the hypothesis using this confidence interval.

Answer (score -2):

It's not much of an issue. A general proposition is that ***upon simulation a sample repeatedly (say for 1000 times), you get close to the population parameters if not juxtapose those.*** Let's take an example; say that you have 10K records in a sample, and don't know what the population is. And want to find out whether the sample mean (xbar) or the median is the true representation of the population mean (mu). You will have to simulate the sample say for 1000 times, taking a separate and small sample, say 10 values, each time recording sample mean for those smaller samples. One premise of the idea is that upon plotting those 1000 values, you should end up with a normal distribution. You then take the RMSE of both the given xbar and the median and take the one having lesser RMSE for the "Maximum Likelihood Estimator" (MLE) for the population parameter mu.

Having said that, I admit from the metaphorical leaves of my experience that it is always important to report and be transpicuous with the audience and readers, for in my opinion it is very difficult to always get the right answer. Nonetheless, people should always be kept informed of what they are consuming.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to find any part of this answer that is generally correct.  Resampling from a sample does not get you any closer to the population parameters, no matter how many times you resample.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me on the matter @whuber . Could you please elaborate how on what principles then are the process of 'estimation' and 'simulations' based upon (not arguing on this, just asking a general question considering my limited expertise on this subject)?